# Prove convergence of martingale to zero

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Suppose  that $X_n$ are iid and for $\theta > 0$ we have the martingale: 
$$M_n = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\theta X_i}}{ (E[e^{\theta X_i}])^n}$$
I know by the martingale convergence theorem that $M_n \rightarrow M_\infty$ almost surely as $n\rightarrow\infty$, but how can I find what the actual limit $M_\infty$ is? I think it's zero but I am having trouble formalising the proof (I was thinking of using Jensen's inequality and the squeeze law but this feels wrong to me).

I also have another related question that asks me to prove that $(M_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow a$ for some $a \geq 0$ (which I need to explicitly identify) but if I think that $M_\infty = 0$ then I'm not sure I understand how to find this limit either. Could anyone provide any tips?

Comment: Presumably $X_n$ satisfies $E[e^{\theta X_n}] < \infty$ for the chosen $\theta$ and also $P(X_n = a) \neq 1$ for any $a$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I was given the first assumption - the second one I wasn't given, can you explain why you would assume that $P(X_n = a) \neq 1$?

Comment: It's more of a convenience than it is a requirement for the problem to make sense.  Specifically, If $P(X_n = a) = 1$ for some $a,$ then $M_n = 1$ almost surely, which is a degenerate case we probably want to explicitly ignore.

Comment: As @Mick shows, $\lim_m(M_n)^{1\over n} ={e^{\theta\Bbb E[X_1]}\over\Bbb E[e^{\theta X_1}]}$. By Jensen, this limit is $<1$ (unless $X_1$ is degenerate), from which $\lim_nM_n=0$ a.s. follows.

Comment: @JohnDawkins is right, the limit is just 0. Guess it was too late to realize...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the logarithm of $\sqrt[n]{M_n}$, i.e.
$$ \log \sqrt[n]{M_n} = \frac1n \log M_n = \theta \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i -  \log \mathbb E[e^{\theta X_1}] .$$
If $\exists \theta>0$ s.t. $\mathbb E[e^{\theta X_1}]<\infty$, then all the moments are finite, hence we have SLLN, and so
$$ \lim_n \log \sqrt[n]{M_n} \stackrel{a.s.}{=} \theta \mathbb E[X_1]- \log \mathbb E[e^{\theta X_1}], $$
meaning that 
$$ \lim_n \sqrt[n]{M_n} \stackrel{a.s}{=} \frac{e^{\theta \mathbb E[X_1]}}{\mathbb E[e^{\theta X_1}]}. $$